# How can I store individual characters of a word in an array for late use

Tags: javascript, html

so what I want to do is get a random word, and put each individual characters of it in an array to then create `divs` like

```
for(i = 0; i <= wlength; i++ ){
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = 'aa';
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
  div.innerHTML = "- " + i;
  div.style.left = '32px';
}
```

and instead of `div.innerHTML = "- " + i;`

It would create a `div` for each individual characters of a word.

How can I do that? Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: How do want the output to be?

Comment: I want the output to be a div with a character of the word. If the word is "food" then it would be a div with a f, a div with a o, another div with a o, and finally another div with a d.

Comment: what do you mean by *"How can I store individual characters of a word in an array for late use"*? it differs from the showed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function listChars(word){
  var wLength = word.length, div;
    for(var i = 0; i < wLength; i++ ){
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'aa';
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('- ' + word[i]));
    div.style.left = '32px';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
}

var word = 'cat';
listChars(word);
```

Comment: Could u explain what's happening there?

Comment: @DuarteArribas for each character in word it creates a div. thats whats happening there

Comment: How would I be able to switch the "hello" to another variable?

Comment: @DuarteArribas you can create a function and call it whenever you want

Comment: Yeah I know, but that doesn't really answer my question, instead of 'hello' if the word is 'food' how can i store it in a variable and put it there?
Like:
var anyword = "food"
var word = anyword, wLength = word.length, div;

Comment: @DuarteArribas take a look

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
let word = 'randomword'
let char = []

for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  char.push(word[i])
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  div.id = char[i]
  document.body.appendChild(div)
}
```

```js
    let word = 'randomword'
    let char = []

    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      char.push(word[i])
      const div = document.createElement('div')
      div.id = char[i]
      div.innerHTML = char[i]
      /*
      or if you need elements that you can manipulate...
      ...
      const ele = document.createElement('text')
      const txt = document.createTextNode(char[i])
      ele.appendChild(txt)
      div.appendChild(ele)
      */
      document.body.appendChild(div)
    }
```

```css
div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  background: grey;
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: orange;
}
```

**And here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/mqmdML?editors=1111) that you can play around with.**

Comment: @DuarteArribas i've added a codepen and inline code demonstration

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the word and take for every letter a new div.

```js
var i,                                    // declare all variables on top
    word = 'Weltschmerz',                 // choose a right word
    wlength = word.length,
    div;

for (i = 0; i < wlength; i++) {
    div = document.createElement('div');  // create a new element
    div.id = 'aa' + i;                    // build a unique id for later access
    div.innerHTML = word[i];              // take the letter as content
    div.style.left = '32px';              // does not work here, because of relative pos
    div.style.display = 'inline';         // style some things
    div.style.border = '1px green solid';
    div.style.padding = '2px';
    div.style.margin = '1px';
    document.body.appendChild(div);       // append actual div to body
}

document.getElementById('aa0').style.borderColor = 'red';
```

Comment: Could u explain what's happening there?

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness:

```js
let myWord = 'hello'
myWord.split('')
  .map((c, i) => {
    let div = document.createElement('div')
    div.id = 'aa' + i
    div.innerHTML = c
    div.style.left = '32px'
    return div
  })
  .forEach(div => document.body.appendChild(div))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to map the words characters to an HTML string containing the divs, which you can assign to the dom easily:

```
var word = "Strebsamkeit";

document.body.innerHTML = Array.from(word).map( char =>
  `<div id='aa'>
     ${char}
   </div>`
).join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to replace each character with the div HTML:

```js
var word = "cat"

var html = word.replace(/(.)/g, '<div id="aa$1" style="left: 32px;">- $1</div>\n')

document.body.innerHTML = html

console.log(html)
```